# Using Python 3.7 and Selenium, I can't figure out how to troubleshoot my code for out of Viewport elements

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to use various methods to troubleshoot my code to figure out why I can't use the "actions.move_to_element" method to move to an offscreen element, and click on it.

I am trying to get this line of code:

```
Off_Screen_Element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-btn-cta")
```

to act on this HTML element, which I must scroll to see. It is a button to accept the conditions of me booking a class time:

```
<button class="c-btn-cta c-btn-cta--chevron modal-class-action js-terms-agreement-cta" data-class-action="book-class" data-class-action-step="class-action-confirmation" data-workout-id="205911" data-club-id="229" aria-disabled="false" data-waitlistable="true">Confirm</button>
```

I get no syntax error, but when I use this line of code:

```
print(Off_Screen_Element.text)
```

it returns nothing. No exception or error. Just nothing. What am I doing wrong?

The key chunk of code I am using is this. Note, some is commented out for trouble-shooting I am trying to do. There is a large chunk of code of this script I am not posting, as it is working fine.

```
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#Using Firefox to access the Web
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

#profile.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
profile.update_preferences()

#profile.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_id("js-workout-booking-agreement-input").click()
Off_Screen_Element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-btn-cta")
#actions = ActionChains(driver)
#actions.move_to_element(Off_Screen_Element).click()

print(Off_Screen_Element.text)
```

Edit: This is the entire script:

````
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Using Firefox to access the Web
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

#profile.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
profile.update_preferences()

#profile.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.maximize_window()

# Open the website
driver.get('https://www.goodlifefitness.com/book-workout.html#no-redirect')
time.sleep(8)

# click on the sign in tab to get Login Window
driver.find_element_by_class_name('c-header__login-text').click()

# finding the Login Window User ID Box and sending the Login ID
User_ID = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-login-email')
User_ID.send_keys('yyyyyyy')

#Finding the Login Window Password Box and sending the Password
Password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-login-password')
Password.send_keys('xxxxxxx')

#Finding the Login Window Log-In Button and Clicking on it
driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-login-submit').click()

#Pause a few seconds until the My Account Button appears
time.sleep(5)

#Find the unordered list that contains the 4th day (data-index 3) and then click on the element that is the 4th day
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[@data-index='3']").click()

time.sleep(5)

Day_of_Timeslot = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="day-number-4"]')
Precise_Timeslot = Day_of_Timeslot.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[@data-index='2']")
Actual_Button = Precise_Timeslot.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@data-class-action='book-class']").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("js-workout-booking-agreement-input").click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-class-action='book-class']"))).click()
#Off_Screen_Element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-btn-cta")
#actions = ActionChains(driver)
#actions.move_to_element(Off_Screen_Element).click()```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems element is not visible on the page. Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector for the **button**

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-class-action='book-class']"))).text)

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-class-action='book-class']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that method. But that leads to a follow up question: Is the "move_to_element" option not also a viable option?

Comment: @VinceSnetterton : `move_to_element` option is viable option. What I have suggested wait for the to load & clickable. You can also use java scripts executor to click on the element which is out of view port

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I copy/pasted the libraries and the 2nd line of text.

Comment: I am getting these errors:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/OpenSite5.py", line 53, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-class-action='book-class']"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: My code is now: driver.find_element_by_id("js-workout-booking-agreement-input").click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-class-action='book-class']"))).click()

Comment: I also apologize for the formatting, I can't figure out how to block the code and errors in a reply. I did copy/paste.

Comment: @VinceSnetterton : Can you share the webpage of the url you are trying?

Comment: driver.get('https://www.goodlifefitness.com/book-workout.html#no-redirect')

Comment: I will add ALL the code in my original post.

Comment: @VinceSnetterton : Without login credential  I can't login. If possible create a dummy account and share credential as well.Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't create a dummy account. I will try to troubleshoot the code by increasing the wait time in WebDriverWait command, and manually scrolling down the page, to see if if that gives any more information to explain the exceptions.